# Process.Start not executing .exe after publish on IIS 10

Tags: .net, iis, exe, publish, process.start

I have one tool(Consider name "abc") which trigger some stream.str to be executed. I have prepared one ASP.NET Core API application to run that tool abc.exe after execution this exe as a output one log file is created, However this is not working after publishing to IIS Server.My server Configurations are : Windows 2016 Server,IIS 10, application developed with .Net 6, VS 2022. with same code I create one console application and run that console .exe on server that its works perfect and log file is also created. but not working with API application.

please advise, am i missing in settings on server?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Testabc()
{
    string username = "xyz";
    string passowrd = "\"####124345rTw\"";
    string stream = "D:\\Trail\\tra\\Stream.str";
    string databasenodeepassword = "\"awugfjksdfhvlsdhfoiej\"";
    string databasenodedatasource = " 
    {\\"0.0.0.0\\",\\"fgh\\",\\"fggh!\\"}";

   string log = "D:\\Trail\\tra\\Log\\271626eb-c8f4-4c6d-827c- 
   0b5d69f5f48f.log";

   string command = $"-server -username {"\""}{username}{"\""} -port 
   1001-password {passowrd} -stream {"\""}{stream}{"\\""} - 
   epassword={databasenodeepassword} - datasource={"\""} 
   {databasenodedatasource}{"\""} -execute -log {"\""}{log}{"\""}";

   string WorkingDirectory = @"D:\\abc\\abc_Batch\\bin";
   string result= RunCommandabcexe(command, WorkingDirectory);
   return Content(result);
}

private string RunCommandabcexe(string command, string workingDirectory)
{
   string strsecureString=string.Empty;
    System.Security.SecureString secureString = new 
    System.Security.SecureString();

   char\[\] password = "sgfdg9879=".ToCharArray();

   foreach (var item in password)
   {
     secureString.AppendChar(item);
   }
   strsecureString = secureString.ToString();
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   Process process = new Process
   {
   StartInfo = new 
   ProcessStartInfo("D:\\abc\\abc_Batch\\bin\\abc.exe", $"{command}") 
   {
    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    Domain = "abcgroup",
    UserName = "QWERTy",
    Password = secureString
    }
  };

process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =\> sb.AppendLine($"output : {e.Data}");

process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =\> sb.AppendLine($"error : {e.Data}");

process.Start();
int processid = process.Id;
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Several differences matter, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Is there any error message when .exe not execute? Another thing is what application identity you set? Does the app pool identity have permission to run .exe file?

Answer (score 0):

1. have you tried to run the code inside IIS Express from Visual Studio before publishing in IIS?
2. use try... catch to verify error returned.
3. add a working directory inside: StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(){ WorkingDirectory = ..... }

Luc